# Merging debug info when merging static libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries, pdb-files

We build two static libraries, let's call them LibA and LibB.

In Visual Studio, I've set up a solution with projectA & projectB, such that for projectB, under `Configuration Properties -> Librarian -> General -> Additional Dependencies` I've added LibA. This makes VS merge LibA into the generated LibB. This is done since we do not want to change which static libraries we ship to customers.

Now, both LibA and LibB are built with 'Program Database' as the debug information format, and once I link LibB into the final binary, I get warnings of LibA.pdb not being found. This leads me to believe that the debug information from LibA is not being merged into LibB, so I would like to do that myself. Although, I can't find any tools for doing so. Again, I'd rather not ship an extra file if possible.

A workaround I've thought of, but not tried yet, would be to build LibA using 'C7 compatible' as the debug information format. Hopefully, Visual Studio would be smart enough to extract that information and add it to the pdb created for LibB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I merge multiple PDB files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528105/how-do-i-merge-multiple-pdb-files)

Comment: Possible dup of [Including .pdb files with librarian in Visual Studio][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14276129/1823963